# Oracle SQL Developer macOS issue

Tags: macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using MacBook Pro 2018 macOS Mojave and I've reinstalled SQL Developer and Java JDK 11 several times but this weird problem still continues.

The problem is I can't close welcome page and can't create new connection also. I shared a screenshot about the problem.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2y7p.png)

Answer (score 1):

Easier than that:

echo "SetJavaHome "`/usr/libexec/java_home` >> ~/.sqldeveloper/20.2.0/product.conf

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

We only support Oracle JDK 8

You can have both on your machine, but you have to tell the application to use the 8 home.

[Here's how](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-8-on-a-mac-with-sql-developer-4-1/)

[image]

Comment: I deleted Java 11 and installed JDK 8 but still same bug or something going on. Can't close Welcome Page or can't create a new connection because I can't see the texts properly.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8? Try opening preferences and see if you can switch look and feel. If that doesn't work, delete the .sqldeveloper folder in your $Home directory